# how do I access arguments using Modal route.of(context) (Named Route) from Categories to Sub-categories in developing an OLX clone, 2022

Tags: android, ios, flutter, categories, ads

I'm developing a classified listing app like the OLX but I currently have challenges accessing the subcategories from the Categories widgets. Whenever, any category is clicked, I'm expecting such category to appear as the header of the subcategory being accessed. The error occurs at the "**DocumentSnapshot argument = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;**" I've tried several methods without success. Please, can someone help spot what I,m not doing right? thanks in advance.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CategoryListScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoryListScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String id = 'categoryListScreen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final CollectionReference _categories =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('categories');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.cyan.shade800),
        title: Text(
          "Categories",
          style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
              color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: _categories.snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
          if (streamSnapshot.hasError) {
            return Container();
          }
          if (streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final DocumentSnapshot doc = streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index];
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: ListTile(
                  //To subcategories
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, SubCatList.id, arguments: doc);
                  },
                  leading: Image.network(
                    doc['catImage'],
                    width: 40,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    doc['catName'],
                    style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                        fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  trailing: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                    size: 12,
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
    
    
    
    
    class SubCatList extends StatelessWidget {
      const SubCatList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
      static const String id = 'subCatList';
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        
        DocumentSnapshot argument = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments; //this is is where the error is.
    
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.cyan.shade800),
            title: Text(
              //"SubCat",
              argument['catName'],
              style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                  color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you give us the exact error?

Comment: Thanks for your response. The error is on this line of code: DocumentSnapshot argument = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;                    
 //The error message is: A value of the 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of the type 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the type to 'DocumentSnapshot<Object?>.

Comment: Try `ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as DocumentSnapshot`. But generally is is better to define your own classes to hold arguments, [see here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments).

Comment: Thanks for your help!                                      
DocumentSnapshot argument = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as DocumentSnapshot; works. Issue resolved.